# how to bind 2 functions to a key and how to alternate between them

Tags: python, tkinter

how can we alternate between two functions using one key, I have to two functions in a nested function and when i bind this to a key, both functions run, how can we alternate between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to remember the last action and select to do the other one in the callback function. In my example I'm doing this by using a `StringVar()` but this can be done in any number of ways.

Then just check the state in the callback function and apply the desired action:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200+800+50')

def do():
    if info.get() == 'Change bg -> red':
        b.config(bg='red')
        info.set('Change bg -> tan')
    else:
        b.config(bg='tan')
        info.set('Change bg -> red')

info = StringVar()
info.set('Change bg -> red')
b = Button(root, textvariable=info, command=do)
b.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```